# (timecourse) regression analysis help

Tags: regression

My research aims to investigate the effect of earthquake events across the United States on visiting healthcare locations (i.e., people living in the same city where an earthquake has just occurred are more likely to visit healthcare locations).

I will be filtering the data to look at visits 7 days prior to the event and 7 days after the event. Since earthquakes occur multiple times throughout the years, I have to identify the date every event happens, together with the visits 7 days before and after. I will then add a dummy variable signifying pre-post the event in my regression model. I will fit it in a mixed effect model, with the prior and post as the fixed effect and city as random effects (for variability in cities)

Is this analysis fundamentally correct to look at the effect of earthquakes on subsequent healthcare visits? This reminds me of a Difference in Difference regression but I am instructed to not use any non-earthquake events for this analysis (thus, I don't have a non-treatment control group). Hence, I am worried that my analysis makes sense and will help me answer my question.